# What does $r(x, w, y)$ mean if all of them are variables?

Tags: derivatives

I'm trying to find a way to get $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$'s result as $2(xw - y) * r$. I have no idea how to do it, but the derivative of $\frac{d}{dw}\left(xw\:-\:y\right)\cdot \:r$ is $\frac{d}{dw}(\left(xw\:-\:y\right)\cdot \:r(x,w,y))$ as can be seen [here](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/derivative-calculator/%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Bdw%7D%5Cleft(%5Cleft(xw%20-%20y%5Cright)%5Ccdot%20r%5Cright)) (if I understood right). $r$ is a variable, not a function, and outside of functions, I haven't seen variables separated with commas.

Any idea what does it mean?

Comment: Perhaps your calculus textbook has "chain rule for partial derivatives" listed in the index.  Writing $r(x,w,y)$ merely means that $r$ is a function of the three variables $x,w,y$.

Comment: For what function are you trying to take the partial derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}$?

Comment: The symbolab webapp (your link) is interpreting "r" as a function of x,w,y. This may not be the case in your textbook. It would be helpful if you could post the full question